# erasing parts of the loaded image by mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

I have loaded an image in my panel.I want to erase the parts of that image by using the mouse(dragging on the panel).Here is my code to load my image:

```
 private void drawP_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, new Point(0, 0));
    }
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.
Updated:
sorry not to say earlier,I have set another image(image2) as background of the panel and I want it to be seen after erasing myImage(image loaded with the code above).

Comment: Question is very simple but answer is really difficult

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm going to assume that you want this feature to work like the eraser on paint.

there are 3 events you are going to need
   1.mousedown - to call the first erase and open up the mousemove event method.
   2.mouseup - to stop the mousemove event method
   3.mousemove - just to call the erase method

Code: //part pseudo as im not in visual studio right now :(

```
//global vars 
   bool enable = false;

   void erase(Point mousepoint)
   {
      Point f = (mousepoint.X - yourpanel.left?, mousepoint.Y - yourpanel.top?); 
      //gets mouse position on accual picture;

      yourImageGraphics.fillreactangle( f.X - 10, f.Y+10, 20,20 ,Color.White)
      //                                 int X  ,  int Y, width , height, color
   }

   void mousedown(?)
   {
        enable=true;
        erase(Cursor.Position //but you get this from e?);
   }

   void mouseup(?);
   {
        enable=false;
   }

   void mousemove(?)
   {
       if (enable) 
          erase(e.Position?);
   }
```

Also it looks like you are going to have to make a graphics object for your panel :(
I hope this helps because question was a bit vague.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the guestion,sorry not to do it earlier.I think this answer draw white points on the panel so I cant see the background image after erasing.

Answer (score 1):

Here I created simple example. Of course it can be done better, but I just wondering how to do it... so sharing my results.

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    private Bitmap image;
    private Rectangle imgRect;

    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
        image = new Bitmap(@"C:\image.jpg");
        imgRect = new Rectangle(0,0,image.Width, image.Height);
    }

    private void main_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }

    private void main_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.X < image.Width && e.Y < image.Height)
        {
           image.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, Color.Magenta);//change pixel color;
           image.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta);//Make image transparent
           Invalidate(imgRect);
        }
    }
}
```

...and lets test

[image]

Ha! scared that I deleted his eye :)

Comment: Avoid the expensive MakeTransparent() call by making the pixel transparent right away.  Color.FromArgb() with an alpha of 0.  A bit creepy btw.

Answer (score 0):

A `TextureBrush` on a pen can be used for erasing.

Working example (image1 and image2 are the same size images):

```
Bitmap bmp1;
TextureBrush tb;
Point _LastPoint;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DoubleBuffered = true;

  bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"c:\image1.png");
  tb = new TextureBrush(new Bitmap(@"c:\image2.png"));
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    if (!_LastPoint.IsEmpty) {
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
      using (Pen p = new Pen(tb, 15)) {
        p.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
        p.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
        g.DrawLine(p, _LastPoint, e.Location);
      }
    }
    _LastPoint = e.Location;
    this.Invalidate();
  }
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  _LastPoint = Point.Empty;
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: I see you have added " this.DoubleBuffered = true; " .as I have other codes in my project,I don't want the hole project to be doublebuffered.Is there another way? Or Can I add it anywhere else?

Comment: @AsmaGood It was just for my example, which is using a form, not a panel.  You should be using a double-buffered panel if you do a lot of drawing, which it sounds like you are.  I think I covered that in one of your [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8432347/719186).

Comment: Thanks a lot  LarsTech for your attention and answers

Comment: I don't know how to use your way in a panel.I also don't know how to make a panel double buffered although you explaind before.Please write the hole codes for a panel.I'm new in this field.